# Compute the percentage change over multiple pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume that I have two distinct pandas dataframes, that have exactly the same structure:

`df1`:

```
+---+---------+------+------+------+
|   | summary | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 0 | count   | 10   | 10   | 10   |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 1 | mean    | 4    | 5    | 5    |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 2 | stddev  | 3    | 3    | 3    |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 3 | min     | 0    | -1   | 5    |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 4 | max     | 100  | 56   | 47   |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
```

and `df2`:

```
+---+---------+------+------+------+
|   | summary | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 0 | count   | 15   | 15   | 5    |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 1 | mean    | 2    | 2.5  | 2.5  |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 2 | stddev  | 3    | 3    | 3    |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 3 | min     | 0    | -1   | 5    |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 4 | max     | 50   | 56   | 47   |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
```

For every entry, I would like to compute the percentage change between the values of the two dataframes. I am aware that there is a function [`pct_change()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html), however this works only on the same pandas dataframe. 
The desired output is

```
+---+---------+------+------+------+
|   | summary | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 0 | count   | 50%  | 50%  | -50% |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 1 | mean    | -50% | -50% | -50% |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 2 | stddev  | 0%   | 0%   | 0%   |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 3 | min     | 0%   | 0%   | 0%   |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 4 | max     | -50% | 0%   | 0%   |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
```

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create index by strings columns, divide DataFrames by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html), subtract `1` by [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html), multiple by [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
df = df2.set_index('summary').div(df1.set_index('summary')).sub(1).mul(100).reset_index()
print (df)
  summary  col1  col2  col3
0   count  50.0  50.0 -50.0
1    mean -50.0 -50.0 -50.0
2  stddev   0.0   0.0   0.0
3     min   NaN   0.0   0.0
4     max -50.0   0.0   0.0
```

EDIT:

If need `pct_change` between DataFrames in list, df1 with df2, df2 with df3...:

```
L = [df1, df2]
df = (pd.concat(L, keys=range(len(L)))
        .set_index('summary', append=True)
        .groupby(level=1)
        .pct_change())

print (df)
             col1  col2  col3
    summary                  
0 0 count     NaN   NaN   NaN
  1 mean      NaN   NaN   NaN
  2 stddev    NaN   NaN   NaN
  3 min       NaN   NaN   NaN
  4 max       NaN   NaN   NaN
1 0 count     0.5   0.5  -0.5
  1 mean     -0.5  -0.5  -0.5
  2 stddev    0.0   0.0   0.0
  3 min       NaN   0.0   0.0
  4 max      -0.5   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: I provided a fairly minimal example. How would you deal with more than 2 pandas dataframes? In reality, I'd have 10-15 different dataframes.

Comment: @Tokyo - Not understand - what is expected output in 15 dataframes?

Comment: The first approach works perfectly (for two dataframes). The second approach does not generate the same results though

Answer (score 0):

You can just concat your 2 datframes into one

`df = pd.concat([df1,df2])`

and use the `pct_change()` function and setting the `periods`parameter to the number of columns in your DataFrames.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
((df2-df1)/df1).style.format('{:.0%}')
```

Comment: I provided a fairly minimal example. How would you deal with more than 2 pandas dataframes? In reality, I'd have 10-15 different dataframes.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to compute pairwise percentage change for 10-15 dataframes? Just swap df1 and df2 for appropriate dataframes then.